# Using R to create a frequency word cloud using just a column

Tags: r, frequency

If I have a simple df as follows:

```
mtcars 
               mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt ... 
Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.62 ... 
Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.88 ... 
Datsun 710    22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.32 ... 
               ............
```

Assumming column one (row.names) is a long list of cars, how would I create a frequency word cloud using just that column. I tried `wordcloud(mtcars$row.names)` but got following error:

> Error in UseMethod("TermDocumentMatrix", x) :    no applicable method
>   for 'TermDocumentMatrix' applied to an object of class "NULL"

Perhaps wordcloud is the wrong package?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try typing `mtcars$row.names` at the console?

The way to get the row names as a vector is to use `rownames(mtcars)`. Like this:

```
library(wordcloud) # this requires the tm and NLP packages

wordcloud(rownames(mtcars), min.freq=1)  # w/o min.req=1, you get just "merc"
```

[image]

Comment: Great thanks. This works. I tried the same approach to a character vector that is [1:300000] and R kept computing indefinitely. I even raised the frequency to max and still nothing. But you solved it. thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

You could follow steps something like this (I have not run this code):

```
library(tm)

# assuming your vector of names is mtcars$row.names, which I doubt but take for granted:

text <- Corpus(VectorSource(mtcars$row.names))
text <- tm_map(text, tolower) # might simplify the vector

tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(text) # turn it into a term document matrix

library(wordcloud)
m <- as.matrix(tdm)  
freq <- sort(rowSums(m), decreasing = TRUE)
wordcloud(words = names(freq), freq = freq, min.freq = 4, random.order = FALSE, 
          col=terrain.colors(8), scale=c(8,.2), max.words=100, rot.per=.15))
```